# Execute command when starting cygwin (from command line)

Tags: bash, command, cygwin, startup, execute

wondering if anyone knows how to execute a command from within bash **without** using scripts.  Ie, I'm using [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com) and running cygwin.bat.  Basically, the default script is:

```
bash --login -i
```

Which is fine for me most of the time.  But sometimes, I want to pass in a directory that I want to be the default.  Eg:

```
cygwin.bat C:\
```

Would ideally change my directory (from within bash / cygwin) to the C: directory.  I've tried to change the `cygwin.bat` file to:

```
if [%1%] EQU [] (bash --login -i)
if [%1%] NEQ [] (bash -i -c "cd %1%")
```

But the `-c "cd %1%"` executes and then immediately exits.  So what I'd like is a flag like `-c`, but that doesn't immediately exit the shell.  Hopefully I didn't miss something blatantly obvious ... thx.

Comment: can't you just create a bash-function that change the directory to c:\ upon invocation: `function cdrive { cd /cygdrive/c; }` what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Possibly he does not want to create a function for each and every possible directory he wants to enter in...

Answer (score 2):

You append a `;bash` to it, ie `bash -i -c "cd %1%; bash"`. Not very pretty though, but I'm unaware of any better solution.